# Handling react-native geolocation update in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, geolocation

I have a react-native application that tracks the user in the background. I also have a Nodejs backend that interacts with firebase. 
I want to update user location in firebase using react-native geolocation but I'm worried that calling the API every time position changes will be too many calls.
How do I handle something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use setInterval to make api call after 5 or 10 seconds or you can calculate the radius that if the user moves 5m or 10m from last updated location then make an api call.

Comment: Wouldn't that still be too many API calls when the number of users increases?

Comment: Well, What I did in past was: 
I stored the user location (lat, long) in a local storage and after 1 hour I was making api call to update these locations as a chunk to the server. 
I think this is more convenient if you will have large number of users.

Comment: Thanks a lot. will try this

Answer (score 0):

Try using RTDB(Real Time Database) since Google charges you for capacity instead of read/writes. This is how I update my GeoLocation in my apps for Firebase.